# How to avoid syntax errors when inputting multiple print functions to output a name plaque

Tags: python, python-3.7

I recently began programming using Python 3.7.4. and it is my first ever programming software. Despite Python being considered one of the easiest programming languages, I still am terribly bad at it. However, I really do want to learn.

I am creating a simple project where it first requires users to enter any name. I used an input function within a string, however, I wish to also have the name printed within a plague so it looks a little bit fancier.

The main issue is that it crashes since every print function after the first one is apparently treated differently by Python which results in an Invalid Syntax

I have tried to change the indentations and parenthesis but it would still provide a syntax error. More details on what I did below.

This is what I have:

```
name=str(input(print(4*"*"+len(name)*"*"+4*"*")
               print("*"+3*" "+len(name)*" "+3*" "+"*")
               print("*  "+1*"_"+name+1*"_"+"  *")
               print("*"+3*" "+len(name)*" "+3*" "+"*")
               print(4*"*"+len(name)*"*"+4*"*")))
```

The first print function right after input is fine, however, the others are not. I find it weird because I tried to define this function on its own (without the str(input()) and it worked but when I put in inside my main mini-program in the above format, the other print functions become an Invalid syntax. I apologize if my question is too big because I realize how obvious this could be for experienced programmers.

Is there a limit to the number of print functions we can put inside an input function?
If that is the case, how should I go about creating a plaque around the name?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't put `print` inside `input`. `input` is used to `read` user input. Were you looking for `name = input('Enter your name: ')` ?

Comment: The problem is you have multiple arguments given to `input`, but you don't have commas between them; which is a syntax error. Why are you calling `print` here though? `input` automatically prints out whatever you give it.

Comment: How are you teaching yourself Python? It is probably best to follow a beginner's tutorial so you understand the basics before you start your own projects. Once you have a solid understanding of the `print` and `input` functions, you can return to this project

Comment: Please go through the tutorial [thinkpython](http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/html/index.html). I really recommend it :)